# Warning! UIStoryboardPopoverSegue "deprecated" in objective c when i open the upopovercontroller>.,,

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopover

I want to open the UIPopoverPresentationController through prepare for segue method I tried the below code but it showing some warning error message like "UIStoryboardPopoverSegue is deprecated : first deprecatedin iOS 9.0"- access destinationviewcontroller.popoverpresentation from your segue's perform selector or override of performs....

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popover = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
    CGFloat horizontalInset = (self.frame.size.width - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    CGFloat verticalInset = (self.frame.size.height - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;

    popover.popoverController.popoverLayoutMargins =
    UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                     verticalInset,
                     horizontalInset,
                     verticalInset,
                     horizontalInset);
}}
```

Comment: What is your question? Yes, UIStoryboardPopverSegue was deprecated. So don't use it. Use a different type of segue. They will be available from Interface Builder.

Comment: i need to open this popover as per the segue size whatever i calculated in the above code how to use that with out i declare "UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popover = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;" this line thats it...

Comment: the popover segue has been deprecated. You should use another type. Look in interface builder. It shows all the types there. Like `present as popover`.

Comment: that means,! how i should remove that warning and use that custom UIEdgeInsetsMake from the segue...!!

Comment: @Fogmeister how i should use this tell with some example please thank u...

Comment: In InterfaceBuilder, select the segue. In property inspector, click the "Kind" drop down. Select "present as popover".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148221/discussion-between-hari-narayanan-and-fogmeister).